# I'm having a problem with a char variable (New to programming with C)

Tags: c, macos, char, scanf, conversion-specifier

I keep getting one bug in the terminal which says:

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%c", namehumaninput);
           ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The course I am taking is saying that all I need to do is have a char variable and thats it, use that with nothing else but clearly something is wrong.
Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
    //Lesson 9
    int inputage;
    double gpainput;
    char namehumaninput;
    printf("Wat ur age?\n");
    scanf("%d", &inputage); // scanf(); is how you do an input. You MUST have & behind a variable after a %d!!
    printf("You are %d years old\n", inputage);
    printf("Was yo GPA?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &gpainput); // %lf is for double variables when using scanf() but using printf() it uses %s for variables. Confusing, I know.
    printf("Your GPA is %f\n", gpainput);
    printf("Wos yo name now that ive asked yo fo yo gpa and age\n");
    scanf("%c", namehumaninput); // %c is universal for both
    printf("Really? Yo name is %c?\n", namehumaninput);
```

I have the `stdio` and `stdlib` libraries imported and am using MacOS.

Comment: You seem to know that you need to pass pointers as arguments to the `scanf` function, as you do it in other places. Why don't you do it here? Why do you think it's different with characters and the `%c` format?

Comment: Also, please see the next comment, and [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: Also, before your next question, change the format from `"%c"` to `" %c"` (note the leading space).

Answer (score 1):

This call of scanf

```
scanf("%c", namehumaninput);
```

you need to rewrite at least

```
scanf(" %c", &namehumaninput);
```

The leading space in the format string allows to skip white space characters in the input stream and you need to provide a pointer to a character as the second argument expression.

However this call allows to enter only a single character.

If you want to enter a word then you should write for example

```
char namehumaninput[20];
//...

scanf("%19s", namehumaninput);
printf("Really? Yo name is %s?\n", namehumaninput);
```